# Add data attribute to specific dates (Jquery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Jquery UI datepicker, and I need to add data attributes to specific dates, so I can use it to show events happening on this specific date.

my current state is still pretty simple, and I see the "highlight" does add a "title" attr to the  of the specific dates, but I can't seem to figure it it's even possible to add more custom data attributes.

this is what I get for a highlighted date:

I would like to have even a simple data attribute with the compressed date like data-events-date="12042017", so I can pull the data of this day's events from a list.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // An array of dates
    var eventDates = {};
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/04/2017' )] = new Date( '12/04/2017' ).toString();
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/06/2017' )] = new Date( '12/06/2017' ).toString();
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/20/2017' )] = new Date( '12/20/2017' ).toString();
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/25/2017' )] = new Date( '12/25/2017' ).toString();

    // datepicker
    jQuery('#courses-calendar').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
            var highlight = eventDates[date];
            if( highlight ) {
                 return [true, "event", highlight];
            } else {
                 return [true, '', ''];
            }
         }
    });
});
```

If there's a better yet simple option for it - I'm open for suggestions.
thanks

**UPDATE 1 27/9**

So I went back and changed the way the datepicker works, so I won't have to use data attributes as triggers. problem now - I don't know how to get the "event" class to be added to the dates in my array (think I messed up something there).

this is my new code: https://jsfiddle.net/5mkp1gxn/

Just need to add the class "event" to the dates that appear on the array.

Answer (score 0):

why not just set data like data-events-date="12-04-2017" 
and change code to

```
// datepicker
jQuery('#courses-calendar').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function( date ) {    //does heres date is data-events-date attribute? 
        var highlight = new Date( date.split("-").join("/")).toString();
        if( highlight ) {
             return [true, "event", highlight];
        } else {
             return [true, '', ''];
        }
     }
});
```

#### edited1

I used [Tooltip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to beautify the title of events, where you can use HTML and stuff to show whatever you want...
For example, try to hover one of the dates in `eventDates`:

**It could not work because of localization, try it locally with your date format**

```js
//var a = ["2017/3/04","2017/9/28"];
var events = {
            "course": [{
                "date": "9-28-2017",
                "hour": "17:30",
                "title": "Class Name 1",
                "manager": "Khal Drogo",
                "link": "http://www.google.co.il"
            },
            {
                "date": "9-4-2017",
                "hour": "17:40",
                "title": "Class Name 2",
                "manager": "Little Finger",
                "link": "http://www.google.co.il"
            },
            {
                "date": "9-5-2017",
                "title": "Class Name 3",
                "manager": "Sansa Stark",
                "link": "http://www.google.co.il"
            },
            ]
    };
 a = events["course"];
//var a = {"2017/3/04":"do sth", "2017/9/28":"it works"}
// datepicker
jQuery('#courses-calendar').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var dstring = date.toLocaleString().substring(0,9);
        var dAry = dstring.split("/");
        dAry.push(dAry.shift());
        dstring = dAry.join("-").split(" ").join("");
        var item,isHightlight=false;
        for(var i in a){
         if(a[i].date == dstring){
             isHightlight = true;
             item = a[i];
             break;
         }
        }
        
        //var isHightlight = typeof a[dstring] !== "undefined"?1:0;
        //highlight = date.toString();  //if u want time, use this
        highlight = typeof item !== "undefined" ? "title:"+(item.title+" \ncontent:"+item.manager+" \nlink:"+item.link):undefined;

        if( isHightlight === true ) {
            return [true, "event", highlight];
        } else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="courses-calendar" />
```

#### edited2

if this codes is not you wanted, I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: I don't seem to figure how to proceed from your answer to a working data-events-date. I get a "data is not defined" error in the console. can you please explain the method? thanks.

Comment: I've given u a sample, try it again

Comment: if u want to use 12042017 u can use substring and join to instead of or give me a comment, I'll give u a sample code

Comment: I actually went back and changed the way it works so I won't have to use the data attributes as triggers. although now I can't add the "event" class only to those dates on my array.

Comment: which format you want to show, can u give me a string sample

Answer (score 0):

I used [Tooltip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to beautify the title of events, where you can use HTML and stuff to show whatever you want...
For example, try to hover one of the dates in `eventDates`:

**It could not work because of localization, try it locally with yor date format**

```js
// An array of dates
var eventDates = {
 '27/09/2017': 'EVENT NAME',
 '12/04/2017': 'EVENT NAME',
 '12/06/2017': 'EVENT NAME',
 '12/20/2017': 'EVENT NAME',
 '12/25/2017': 'EVENT NAME'
};

function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

// datepicker
jQuery('#courses-calendar').datepicker({
 beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var dateString = pad(day,2)+'/'+pad(month,2)+'/'+year;
  if(dateString in eventDates) {
   return [true, 'event', eventDates[dateString]];
  } else {
   return [true, '', ''];
  }
 }
});

jQuery(document).tooltip({
 items: '.event',
 content: function() {
  var day = $(this).text();
  var $parent = $(this).closest('td');
  var month = $parent.data('month') + 1;
  var year = $parent.data('year');
  var date = pad(day,2)+'/'+pad(month,2)+'/'+year;
  return date+' - <i>'+eventDates[date]+'</i><br>You can print here whatever you want...<br><b>Even in HTML!</b>';
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-it.js"></script>

<input id="courses-calendar" />
```